# How do I calculate this restricted integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis

How do I calculate this integral?
$$\iint_D x\,dx\,dy$$
where
$$ 
D = \left\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : 4x^2+y^2 \leq 1,\ 2y+4x^2-1 \leq 0 \right\}
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral is zero since your function is odd in $x$, and your domain is symmetric with respect to the line $x=0$.